Using different layout for unauthenticated users in Blazor WASM
I created a new Blazor WASM app targeting .NET 8 -- 8.0.8 to be more specific. The app uses Azure AD B2C for user management and I want to use a different layout for pages designed for public/unauthenticated users.
I was able to get the template that comes out of the box working fine but obviously that template uses a single layout.
I tried using the solution suggested by Steve Sanderson here but when I implemented that clicking the "Login" link no longer works. It doesn't open the popup with user sign-in/sign up page hosted by Azure AD B2C. It also throws the following error:

Here are the changes I've made:
First, I created a very simple PublicLayout.razor that looks like this:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div style="height: 100%;">
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="My App" width="350" />
                    <p style="font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; color: #d7d7d7;">
                        Hello stranger!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

I then updated App.razor to the following as suggested by Sanderson in response to the GitHub question:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            @RouterWithLayout(typeof(MainLayout))
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            @RouterWithLayout(typeof(PublicLayout))
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code {
    RenderFragment RouterWithLayout(Type layoutType) => __builder =>
    {
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@layoutType" />
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@layoutType">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    };
}

Any suggestions on how I can use a different layout for the public/unauthenticated pages of my Blazor WASM app?

Here's how I solved this. I suspect this is obvious to most but this is my first Blazor app so I'm not yet fully proficient in this technology.
I modified my MainLayout.razor which looks like this now:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <NavMenu />
            </div>

            <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
                <LoginDisplay />
            </div>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <div>
                <LoginDisplay />
            </div>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>

    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

I think there's room to optimize this layout but basically, whatever I don't want to display if the user hasn't logged in goes inside the <Authorized></Authorized> section of <AuthorizeView>.
The only reason why <LoginDisplay> component is in both <Authorized> and <NotAuthorized> sections is that I removed CSS classes from the <div> so that it displays properly but as I said, there's a lot of room here for optimization.
And I left all the common elements outside the <AuthorizeView> so that they display in both cases e.g. @Body.
P.S. One last thought on using different layout components for authenticated and anonymous users is that all my research showed me that this particular scenario, though pretty common, wasn't treated as an important matter. There were solutions here and there but they all seemed kind of cumbersome to me. I suspect this is because the team at Microsoft expects an approach like the one I outlined here.
In other words, using a single primary layout and handling authenticated and anonymous scenarios using <AuthorizeView> appears to be what they expect. At least, this is the feeling I get.
Obviously, it's easy enough to create a completely different layout and use it anywhere in the app simply by specifying it inside the component i.e. @layout SomeOtherLayout. Here's the documentation on that. HTH.

In this case, wrapping anything inside  looses common events. For example dropdown/sub menus. Not sure why. Even using procedural logic (CascadingParameter of AuthState) also causes this.

The error confuses me: what's a WebSocket Connection doing in a WASM application.
My Routes.razor would look something like this.  It's a different way of achieving the same result.  I've added a handler to the AuthenticationStateChanged event to refresh the component when necessary.
@using SO78988687.Components.Account.Shared
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@implements IDisposable

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="_layout">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

@code {
    private bool _isAuthenticated;
    private Type _layout => _isAuthenticated ? typeof(Layout.AuthorizedLayout) : typeof(Layout.MainLayout);

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var task = AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        await GetAuthenticationState(task);

        this.AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += this.OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    }

    private async void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        await GetAuthenticationState(task);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    protected async Task GetAuthenticationState(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        var authState = await task;
        _isAuthenticated = authState.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= this.OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    }
}

Note that this approach changes the layout for a public page based on login state.  Is this what you want?
If you want public pages to use the public layout, then you need to set the default layout in Routes and then change the layout in the pages using the @layout Layout.MainLayout directive.

Yes, this is what I want but there seems to be an issue. I created a new layout named PublicLayout.razor by copying and pasting what's inside MainLayout.razor. The only thing I removed is the <div class="sidebar"><NavMenu /></div>. When I run the app, it uses the public layout but once I log in, it still appears to be using the public layout. Any idea why?

I have a feeling this is some caching issue. The MainLayout.razor may be getting cached and not reflecting changes before and after authentication.

I think part of the problem is that authentication status is checked in OnInitializedAsync() lifecycle event. When authentication status has changed, I don't think the MainLayout.razor will be notified of the change because it's already initialized and being used by the app. I think storing authentication status in a central state container maybe a better idea.

I'm new to Blazor development and realized that I can achieve most if not everything I need using <AuthorizeView>. Thank you for your help!

You may well be right.  I've added an event handler for AuthenticationStateChanged to render the component if the state changes.
